# Obtaining boot.img for unrooted device?

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, rom-flashing, boot, bootloader

I have a Vodafone Smart 4 Turbo / Coolpad 8865U. I cannot find other means of rooting it and to be honest I don't trust most oneclickroot.apks. I am trying to root it manually but I cannot find a way to obtain a boot.img.

I managed to get a .CPB  file which I believe to be the firmware for my phone though I am not sure. However I cannot find a way to unpack it either.

So how can I obtain a boot image for this phone or manage to unpack the .CPB file?

EDIT: I made progress but I'm also back to square one. I found a tool called cpbtool.exe that successfully extract the *.cpb firmware. I then obtained boot.img from there. Modified it so that it boots insecurely and tried to boot the now insecure image using fastboot but the thing just hangs at "booting..."

For some reason it seems like fastboot doesn't really work on my coolpad device despite being oem unlocked.